# Javascript object value not getting proper value

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, closures

I'm writing a class project (we have to build a Frogger game using HTML5 canvas) and I have a a bunch of objects to help me out with different things like collision detection, movement, ect.

The below object is one of those. Each view contains a Frame object which contains a function call hitTest that checks to see if its frame is colliding with the passed in frame. For some reason, `this.lr` retains the value that it was originally set to at the beginning of the game and I can't figure out why it's not updating based on the changing origin point.

```
function Frame(origin, size) {
    this.origin = utility.checkPoint(origin);
    this.size = utility.checkSize(size);
    var self = this;

    this.lr = (function () {
        return utility.checkPoint(new Point(self.origin.x + self.size.width, self.origin.y + self.size.height));
    }());

    this.tr = (function () {
        return utility.checkPoint(new Point(self.origin.x + self.size.width, self.origin.y));
    }());

    this.ll = (function () {
        return utility.checkPoint(new Point(self.origin.x, self.origin.y + self.size.height));
    }());

    /* Returns true if the two frames share any common pixels */

    this.hitTest = function (frame) {
        var isInXBounds = function (p) {
            return (p.x >= self.origin.x && p.x <= self.tr.x);
        };

        var isInYBounds = function (p) {
            return (p.y >= self.origin.y && p.y <= self.lr.y);
        };

        var isContained = function (p) {
            return (isInXBounds(p) && isInYBounds(p));
        };

        return isContained(frame.origin) || isContained(frame.tr) || isContained(frame.lr) || isContained(frame.ll);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're immediately executing the function

```
this.lr = (function () {
    return utility.checkPoint(new Point(self.origin.x + self.size.width, self.origin.y + self.size.height));
}());
```

As a result, lr is being assigned a value right on that spot, and never changes.

What you want is simply:

```
this.lr = function () {
   return utility.checkPoint(new Point(self.origin.x + self.size.width, self.origin.y + self.size.height));
};
```

This defines lr as a *method* that can be called as needed in the future.

Comment: So using closures immediately executes that function? that's not cool. What happens if I were to call Frame.lr somewhere else? Does it always just return the same value originally assigned to it? I feel like that's one of those nuisances of javascript

Comment: @shadow - It's not a nuisance. It's just that you're using the wrong pattern to create your class.

Comment: Hmmm alright fair enough. Is it ok that all my objects are written using closure patterns, as long as my functions internal to that object are methods?

Comment: @Shadow - I think you're using the word "closure" wrongly.  A closure simply means that a function continues to have access to the scope in which it's created, even if that scope would seem to no longer be valid.  (see Nick Zakas's book for a more detailed description)  In a sense all functions form closures when they're defined.  Your problem has nothing to do with closures.

Comment: @shadow - It's pretty obvious that you come from a classical programming background. No, it's not required that you wrap everything in functions.

Comment: Yeah started off in C++ and C. Super duper classical. 

Yeah yeah my mistake, I think I get terminology mixed up a lot. @AaditMShah, could you clarify what you mean? After I correct those internal functions to actually be methods, is my syntax/pattern correct? And if not, what would I need to do to correct it?

Comment: @shadow - you look like you're on the right track once you fix that one problem.  btw, for a good example of a closure in action, check out how `isInXBounds` can still access `self`.  At the point `isInXBounds` is defined, that whole function *closes over* the scope declared in Frame, and has access to local variables declared therein *even after* Frame has exited.

Comment: OHHHHH. That's so neat. Programming geek moment. So then what's the practical use of doing something like 

(function(){ //something }()); When would I use that and why not just do the standard method syntax?

Comment: Awesome. Truly awesome. Just one last question haha, referring back to your example of `isInXBounds`, what would be the effect if I were to change it to `var isInXBounds = (function(){ //do something }());` vs what I have in my question? I now feel as if doing that is good form when defining larger scope objects for, as you said, scope reasons and then internal to all those objects using the standard method declaration form is just fine (and recommended)

Comment: You seem to be addicted to the immediately invoked function expression pattern. You should read about and understand what it is used for before using it everywhere: http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/ It's a really cool feature but don't use it everywhere. You're lucky though. Most people have problems because they don't use it. You have problems because you use it too often.

Comment: Hahahaha sounds like something I would do. Yeah I'll read all these things before I ship off to dreamland. And yes, I LOVEEEEEE that pattern. It looks so fancy.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would write your `Frame` class:

```
Frame.prototype.lr = function () {
    var x = this.origin.x + this.size.width;
    var y = this.origin.y + this.size.height;
    return utility.checkPoint(new Point(x, y));
};

Frame.prototype.tr = function () {
    var x = this.origin.x + this.size.width;
    return utility.checkPoint(new Point(x, this.origin.y));
};

Frame.prototype.ll = function () {
    var y = this.origin.y + this.size.height;
    return utility.checkPoint(new Point(this.origin.x, y));
};

Frame.prototype.isContained = function (point) {
    var isInXBounds = point.x >= this.origin.x && point.x <= this.tr().x;
    var isInYBounds = point.y >= this.origin.y && point.y <= this.lr().y;
    return isInXBounds && isInYBounds;
};

Frame.prototype.hitTest = function (frame) {
    return this.isContained(frame.origin) || this.isContained(frame.tr) ||
           this.isContained(frame.lr) || this.isContained(frame.ll);
};

function Frame(origin, size) {
    this.origin = utility.checkPoint(origin);
    this.size = utility.checkSize(size);
}
```

Prototypal inheritance can be quite daunting for a person who comes from a classical background. Here's a simple explanation for prototypal inheritance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8096017/783743

There are lots of libraries that help classical programmers work with JavaScript. For example my own [augment](https://github.com/javascript/augment) library. Here's how you would write the above class using `augment`:

```
var Frame = Object.augment(function () {
    this.constructor = function (origin, size) {
        this.origin = utility.checkPoint(origin);
        this.size = utility.checkSize(size);
    }

    this.lr = function () {
        var x = this.origin.x + this.size.width;
        var y = this.origin.y + this.size.height;
        return utility.checkPoint(new Point(x, y));
    };

    this.tr = function () {
        var x = this.origin.x + this.size.width;
        return utility.checkPoint(new Point(x, this.origin.y));
    };

    this.ll = function () {
        var y = this.origin.y + this.size.height;
        return utility.checkPoint(new Point(this.origin.x, y));
    };

    this.isContained = function (point) {
        var isInXBounds = point.x >= this.origin.x && point.x <= this.tr().x;
        var isInYBounds = point.y >= this.origin.y && point.y <= this.lr().y;
        return isInXBounds && isInYBounds;
    };

    this.hitTest = function (frame) {
        return this.isContained(frame.origin) || this.isContained(frame.tr) ||
               this.isContained(frame.lr) || this.isContained(frame.ll);
    };
});
```

Also since you want to know what a closure really is I suggest you read the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12931785/783743

Comment: Thanks so much man! You didn't have to go through all that work just for this but that's awesome that you did. I really like both styles of writing objects but is either one more valid than the other or can both be used interchangeably?

Comment: Both can be used interchangeably but I prefer to use the second method. The `augment` library is small but has a bunch of very useful features.

Comment: Oh I meant the prototype pattern vs. my obsession one..haha the immediately executing function one.

Comment: The prototypal pattern is better. That's because methods defined on the prototype are shared between all instances of the class. In your case you're creating the same functions over and over again for every new instance of `Frame`.

Comment: Ah ha! Comprehension success! Thanks for putting up with my questions haha