# javascript event listener with param

Tags: javascript, events, anonymous-function

I have a simple event listener:

```
function listen(evnt, elem, func) {
    if (elem.addEventListener)  // W3C DOM
        elem.addEventListener(evnt,func,false);
    else if (elem.attachEvent) { // IE DOM
         var r = elem.attachEvent("on"+evnt, func);
    return r;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I want to set listeners with a parameter. (the parameter is not set by the event, it is part of specific listener.

What I do and seems to work is:

```
function setlistener (param){

 listen ('custom event', document,
  function (e){
     run_func_with_param(param);
    }
  );
}
```

But I dont understand if its correct because param is not supposed to be defined when the event is fired.

My question is - is it the right way to have run_func_with_param called, each time with the params that was set for it in setlistener? In other words, is param remembered and will be set to the right values when run_func_with_param will be called as result of an event? (there will be multiple listeners with different params for the same event).

Notes: No jQuery/other libraries please.
I'm using a custom event in this case.

Comment: I think **param** will be viable for each event when it's fired. It's called closure. Better explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930272/javascript-closures-vs-anonymous-functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use an anonymous function, the arguments and local variables from the parent scope are still available in the anonymous function.

Thus, your argument named `param` is available inside your anonymous function that is passed to `listen()`.  It isn't passed to that function - it's just available directly from the parent scope.

Here's your function with some annotation in comments:

```
function setlistener (param){
    // param is available here as an argument to setlistener
    // as a normal function argument
    listen ('custom event', document, function (e) {
        // param is still available here directly from the parent scope
        //     in this anonymous function.
        // This is one advantage of using anonymous functions.
        if (e.data.back_button==false){
          run_func_with_param(param);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Sorry but there is something that I dont understand. suppose I call setlistener(1), then I call setlistener(2). Does JS keep two instances of the anonymouse function, each with the parent scope that existed when they were declared?

Comment: @Nir - yes, javascript keeps each scope separately and all the variables in them.  It's called a "closure".  So each call to `setlistener()` will have it's own scope saved with it's own copy of `param` and that closure/scope will exist as long as it's still possible for the anonymous function callback to be called.

Comment: Thanks jfriend00. thats what I was looking for. :-)