# Is a function return necessary to be called a Closure

Tags: javascript, closures

Hey i came across this video on youtube http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KRm-h6vcpxs

which basically explains IIFEs and closures. But what I am not understanding is whether i need to return a function in order to call it a closure.

E.x.

```
function a() {
    var i = 10;
    function b() {
       alert(i);
    }
}
```

in this case can i call it a closure as it is accessing the 'i' variable from the outer function's scope or do i need to return the function like this

```
return function b(){alert(i);}
```

Comment: +1 to @dystroy answer. You dont need to call another function inside a function to close the first one. It's like people that uses `return null`. You dont have to return something to finish the function. Just close it :P

Comment: that's wht i thought but in the video the definition was given like that so i thought i will confirm the same

Comment: @DaGLiMiOuX - OP is asking about [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)), not talking about how to finish a function.

Comment: @nnnnnn he is asking if he needs to return a closure, and I said that to finish a function dont need to return anything, so no closure is needed or return null, etc. Whats the prob with my comment?

Comment: Yes it's a closure. You create a function that captures it's containing environment. However it's not a useful one as you don't ever call it. Generally the whole point it to return it so you can call it later with the captured environment of the containing function... So yes, it's a closure, just not a useful one :)

Comment: @DaGLiMiOuX - To me it sounded like you were simply talking about how to complete the definition of a function, ignoring the topic of closures. _Yes_ it is valid to have a function with no return statement, but again that kind of overlooks the issue the OP is asking about. What do you mean by the phrase "finish the function"?

Comment: @Nav - As jcoder said, for a closure to be _useful_ to you, the programmer, you need a reference to the inner function so that you can call it at some point after the containing function is finished executing. Note that there are ways to get such a reference without returning the inner function, e.g., assigning it as an event handler, or passing it as a callback to some other function.

Comment: @nnnnnn WOW! Big mistake, wanted to say "You dont have to return something to END the function" xD Sorry I was eating and didn't pay too much attention to my comment :P

Comment: This question is rather unclear. You're only showing definitions, but what's important is how they're called.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12931785/783743

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Returning the function changes nothing, what's important is creating it and calling it. That makes the closure, that is a link from the internal function to the scope where it was created (you can see it, in practice, as a pointer. It has the same effect of preventing the garbaging of the outer scope, for example).

Comment: But in the OP's example `b()` isn't actually called, and if it _was_ called from inside `a()` when `a()` finished the whole thing could be garbage-collected since there's no enduring reference to any of the variables in that scope. Closures only really become relevant to the programmer if you start passing function references around (one way or another).

Comment: @nnnnnnnThat is not necessarily true i think as i want to print or append the values to a log directly from the function b() and i do not see a point in returning the function ...what do you think ???

Answer (score 9):

A closure is simply a function which holds its lexical environment and doesn't let it go until it itself dies.

Think of a closure as Uncle Scrooge:

[image]

Uncle Scrooge is a miser. He will never let go of his money.

Similarly a closure is also a miser. It will not let go of its variables until it dies itself.

For example:

```
function getCounter() {
    var count = 0;

    return function counter() {
        return ++count;
    };
}

var counter = getCounter();
```

See that function `counter`? The one returned by the `getCounter` function? That function is a miser. It will not let go of the `count` variable even though the `count` variable belongs to the `getCounter` function call and that function call has ended. Hence we call `counter` a closure.

See every function call may create variables. For example a call to the `getCounter` function creates a variable `count`. Now this variable `count` usually dies when the `getCounter` function ends.

However the `counter` function (which can access the `count` variable) doesn't allow it to die when the call to `getCounter` ends. This is because the `counter` function needs `count`. Hence it will only allow `count` to die after it dies itself.

Now the really interesting thing to notice here is that `counter` is born inside the call to `getCounter`. Hence even `counter` should die when the call to `getCounter` ends - but it doesn't. It lives on even after the call to `getCounter` ends because it escapes the scope (lifetime) of `getCounter`.

There are many ways in which `counter` can escape the scope of `getCounter`. The most common way is for `getCounter` to simply return `counter`. However there are many more ways. For example:

```
var counter;

function setCounter() {
    var count = 0;

    counter = function counter() {
        return ++count;
    };
}

setCounter();
```

Here the sister function of `getCounter` (which is aptly called `setCounter`) assigns a new `counter` function to the global `counter` variable. Hence the inner `counter` function escapes the scope of `setCounter` to become a closure.

Actually in JavaScript every function is a closure. However we don't realize this until we deal with functions which escape the scope of a parent function **and** keep some variable belonging to the parent function alive even after the call to the parent function ends.

For more information read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12931785/783743

Comment: +1 for making the post more interesting with pictures. Miserable people - get lost! :)

Comment: @Jimbo - Thank you. As for the person who downvoted me - if you are reading this may I know why do you believe that my answer deserves a negative vote?

Answer (score 1):

By [definition of *closure*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29), the link from the function to its containing scope is enough. So basically creating the function makes it a closure, since that is where the link is created in JavaScript :-)

Yet, for utilizing this feature we do *call* the function from a *different scope* than what it was defined in - that's what the term "use a closure" in practise refers to. This can both be a lower or a higher scope - and the function does not necessarily need to be `return`ed from the function where it was defined in.

Some examples:

```
var x = null;

function a() {
    var i = "from a";
    function b() {
        alert(i); // reference to variable from a's scope
    }
    function c() {
        var i = "c";
        // use from lower scope
        b(); // "from a" - not "c"
    }
    c();

    // export by argument passing
    [0].forEach(b); // "from a";
    // export by assigning to variable in higher scope
    x = b;
    // export by returning
    return b;
}
var y = a();
x(); // "from a"
y(); // "from a"
```

Answer (score 1):

The actual closure is a container for variables, so that a function can use variables from the scope where it is created.

Returning a function is one way of using it in a different scope from where it is created, but a more common use is when it's a callback from an asynchronous call.

Any situation where a function uses variables from one scope, and the function is used in a different scope uses a closure. Example:

```
var globalF; // a global variable

function x() { // just to have a local scope

  var local; // a local variable in the scope

  var f = function(){
    alert(local); // use the variable from the scope
  };

  globalF = f; // copy a reference to the function to the global variable

}

x(); // create the function
globalF(); // call the function
```

(This is only a demonstration of a closure, having a function set a global variable which is then used is not a good way to write actual code.)

Answer (score 1):

a collection of explanations of closure below. to me, the one from "tiger book" satisfies me most...metaphoric ones also help a lot, but only after encounterred this one...

- closure: in set theory, a closure is a (smallest) set, on which some operations yields results also belongs to the set, so it's sort of "smallest closed society under certain operations".

a) sicp: in abstract algebra, where a set of elements is said to be closed under an operation if applying the operation to elements in the set produces an element that is again an element of the set. The Lisp community also (unfortunately) uses the word "closure" to describe a totally unrelated concept: a closure is an implementation technique for representing procedures with free variables.

b) wiki: a closure is a first class function which captures the lexical bindings of free variables in its defining environment. Once it has captured the lexical bindings the function becomes a closure because it "closes over" those variables.”

**c) tiger book: a data structure on heap (instead of on stack) that contains both function pointer (MC) and environment pointer (EP), representing a function variable;**

d) on lisp: a combination of a function and a set of variable bindings is called a closure; closures are functions with local state;

e) google i/o video: similar to a instance of a class, in which the data (instance obj) encapsulates code (vtab), where in case of closure, the code (function variable) encapsulates data.

f) the encapsulated data is private to the function variable, implying closure can be used for data hiding.

g) closure in non-functional programming languages: callback with cookie in C is a similar construct, also the glib "closure": a glib closure is a data structure encapsulating similar things: a signal callback pointer, a cookie the private data, and a destructor of the closure (as there is no GC in C).

h) tiger book: "higher-order function" and "nested function scope" together require a solution to the case that a dad function returns a kid function which refers to variables in the scope of its dad implying that even dad returns the variables in its scope cannot be "popup" from the stack...the solution is to allocate closures in heap.

i) Greg Michaelson ($10.15): (in lisp implementation), closure is a way to identify the relationship betw free variables and lexical bound variables, when it's necessary (as often needed) to return a function value with free variables frozen to values from the defining scope.

j) histroy and etymology: Peter J. Landin defined the term closure in 1964 as having an environment part and a control part as used by his SECD machine for evaluating expressions. Joel Moses credits Landin with introducing the term closure to refer to a lambda expression whose open bindings (free variables) have been closed by (or bound in) the lexical environment, resulting in a closed expression, or closure. This usage was subsequently adopted by Sussman and Steele when they defined Scheme in 1975, and became widespread.

Comment: Your mention of heap vs stack led me to https://stackoverflow.com/a/29226388/733092.