# What does a closed-over variable mean?

Tags: javascript

The example below was taken from [a StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12931785/1317805) which helps to identify a closure.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    (function f() {
        var i2 = i;
        setTimeout(function g() {
            console.log(i2);
        }, 1000);
    })();
}
```

The following explanation was given:

> For g:
>
> List the variables:
> console is a free variable.
> i2 is a free variable.
> Find the parent scope to which each free variable is bound:
> console is bound to the global scope.
> i2 is bound to the scope of f.
> **In which scope is the function referenced? The scope of setTimeout.
> Hence console is not closed over by g.
> Hence i2 is closed over by g.**

However I am not able to understand the bolded part - could you explain it to me?

Comment: What answer is this taken from? Please link it when you quote it.

Comment: For reference, this is the answer that content is from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12931785/1317805

Comment: i know this is duplicate and i read ur link before you published,But i need to understand the lines i provided in the exampe

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16587104/1048572) to understand what the question "*In which scope is the function referenced?*" means. Basically, do you have access to the free variables **from where the function is called**?

Comment: @user3601733: there are many answers to the question you linked to, some of the others may provide a better explanation. Remember that just because an answer has been accepted doesn't mean it's the easiest to understand.

Answer (score 1):

The term "closed-over" variable in that post means that the **variable is not accessible by the caller** of the function; it is neither seen nor modifiable from the context where the function is being called. Let's modify the code slightly:

```
var mySetTimeout = function (func, timeout) {
    console.log = function (arg) { alert(arg); };
    i = "foobar";
    i2 = "barfoo";
    setTimeout(func, timeout);
};

var i = "peekaboo";

(function f() {
    var i2 = i;
    mySetTimeout(function g() {
        console.log(i2);
    }, 1000);
})();
```

Instead of `setTimeout`, the function `f` calls `mySetTimeout` that *tries* to change both the **value** being logged after the timeout elapses, and the logging function.

After the function `f` has been called and it has returned, **only** the function `g` can see and modify the variable `i2`. However `console` is not closed over, because it is a value in the global scope; if you execute `console.log = function (i) { alert(i); };`, you will get alert box when the timeout fires. However, you cannot read or modify `i2` in `myTimeout` - that function does not see the same variable at all.

Comment: ; if you execute console.log = function (i) { alert(i); };, you will get alert box when the timeout fires. However, you cannot modify i2 in any way..I could not understand this part can u explain it to me thanx