# Open a new page with dblclick event in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

In my pageSetUp() function I have the following snippet of code:

```
    $("#VIDEO_GRID > tbody > tr").dblclick(function (e) {
      $(e.currentTarget.find("td;first"));
      document.draw("videoInfo.html");
      console.log("double clicked");
    })
```

I want to open up a new page called videoInfo.html when a user clicks anywhere within a `<tr>` and ideally I want to grab the data in the first `<td>` of that row. This isn't working, however, and nothing is even being logged out to indicate a user clicked on a row.

I'm also using the datatables API.

Any suggestions?

Comment: post your html code as well

Comment: Do you have an event handler for `click` or other events that happen before `dblclick`? If so, it could be doing a `stopPropagation` somewhere ([documentation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)) and preventing dblclick from ever registering. jQuery does that sometimes due to how it handles these events.

Comment: What is `VIDEO_GRID`?  Is it supposed to be `#VIDEO_GRID`?  Or is the `#` optional now?

Comment: What is `document.draw()`?  I cannot find any documentation for that function.

Comment: Some good answers below.  Is your `pageSetUp()` function definitely being called?

Comment: datatables handles the html

Comment: pageSetUp is definitely being called. The .draw() function is part of the datatables API (https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()), and  document is just a reference to my grid

Answer (score 1):

I hope you using a element with ID "VIDEO_GRID",
That why you like to use like below,

```
$("VIDEO_GRID > tbody > tr").dblclick(function(){
//Code here
});
```

But the problem is you missed the hash before the ID, use like below,

```
$("#VIDEO_GRID > tbody > tr").dblclick(function(){
//Code here
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I had the pound sign in my original code, but that still didn't do it :/

Answer (score 1):

hi try this code to open the Url in new tab

```
function OpenInNewTab(url) {
  var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
  win.focus();
}
```

and there were mistakes in your code try this code:

```
$("#VIDEO_GRID > tbody > tr").dblclick(function (e) {

      OpenInNewTab("videoInfo.html");//replaced this code and using above function to laod make sure about the url
      alert("double clicked");
    })
```

please lemme know if you have any issue with this.
thanks

Comment: I've never seen `window.open` open in a new tab, as far as I know, this is still not possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript, upvoting anyway!

Comment: i think this works try this  window.open("http://google.com", '_blank'); in console it works for me :)

Comment: No, it says popup-blocked ;-P (because it wasn't triggered as the result of a DOM event).  When I allow the popup, it opens in a new window.  You have your browser configured to prefer new tabs to new windows.

Comment: check this link http://jsfiddle.net/TnbYm/16/ and this is working fine.text was changed when pasted it into the comments.

Comment: Sigh, yes...  Except if your browser isn't configured that way.  It's a browser option, not a JavaScript trick.  `window.open` existed a long time before tabbed browsers did.  It's a browser vendor/user preference, not a website's preference.  (Although opening a new window with specific dimensions is not expected to open a new tab in today's browsers, but I'm not discounting a browser may also decide even not to do this in future)

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue : / For some reason, the function isn't even being called at all.

Comment: Can you share your code so I can see why it's not working thanks

Answer (score 0):

**First**

I guess the table is being built upon json source or JavaScript array, in other words it's being injected dynamically, so in such cases you should never use `$(selector).event(handler);` but instead `$(document).on(event, selector, handler);`

So your code will be:

```
$(document).on('dblclick', "#VIDEO_GRID > tbody > tr", function (e) {
      // event handler here
});
```

For more information see this precious [post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

---

**Second**

I would highly recommend you avoid using `document` as a variable name, even your code is working (I doubt it) it will be so confusing to use such name as a reference.

---

**Third**

To load a remote page into a `td` you have nothing to do with `draw` function, but instead you can make *ajax* request to the appropriate page and then inject it into the `td` by `.html` function.

So by putting all points together you will end with something like this:

```
$(document).on('dblclick', "#VIDEO_GRID > tbody > tr", function (e) {
      var me = this;
      request = $.ajax({
          url: 'videoInfo.html'
      });
      // closure used to avoid conflict see the post below for more information
      request.done((function(){
        var _that = me;
        return function(response){ _that.find('td:first').html(response); console.log('page loaded !');}
})());
      request.fail(function(){
        console.log('page not loaded :(');
      });
      console.log("double clicked");
});
```

[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930272/javascript-closures-vs-anonymous-functions) mentioned in the comment.