# Is this an immediately invoked function expression?

Tags: javascript, function, closures

I'm a javascript newbie trying to wrap my mind around this code.
I got it here http://brackets.clementng.me/post/24150213014/example-of-a-javascript-closure-settimeout-inside

I still have a hard time understanding it. Since it involves some pattern I'm not familiar with.

```
// output 0-9, seperated by 1 sec delay.
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(x) { 
        return function() { 
            console.log(x); 
        }; 
    }(i), 1000*i);
}
```

What is the meaning of (i) in this section of code?

```
function(x) { 
    return function() { 
        console.log(x); 
    }; 
}(i)
```

I thought it is an immediately invoked function expression. 
But isn't the correct syntax for that is:

```
(function() {
  // some code
})();
```

Comment: if anyone interested here is another explanation for the same code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930272/javascript-closures-vs-anonymous-functions?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is, indeed, an IIFE. The syntax you quote is an IIFE of 0 arguments; the syntax you asked about is an IIFE of 1 arguments. It will assign `i` to `x` in the inner code. Compare:

```
var print0 = function() {
  console.log("Hello!");
};
print0();
```

is (in isolation) equivalent to

```
(function() {
  console.log("Hello!");
})();
```

Thus the name: you create a function, then immediately invoke it.

However, if you want an argument, nothing really changes:

```
var print1 = function(name) {
  console.log("Hello, " + name);
};
print1("George");
```

is (in isolation) equivalent to

```
(function(name) {
  console.log("Hello, " + name);
})("George");
```

The parentheses here ensure that the function definition will be taken as an expression rather than as a statement. There are other ways to ensure that, a common one being

```
!function() {
  console.log("Hello!");
}();
```

(But there are reasons to prefer the parentheses.) Since you are using it as an argument to the `setTimeout` call, it can't possibly be a statement, so these hacks are not necessary. It is still called "immediately invoked function expression", since you are still constructing a function expression and immediately invoking it.

The reason why an IIFE is used here is to "capture" the value of the variable `i`, rather than the location of `x`. Without the closure trick, you would get 10 timeouts, all outputting `10` (the value of the location denoted by `x` when the `console.log` resolves).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, and the `(i)` is the argument list for the call. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/441498/1048572) for a detailed explanation. The grouping parenthesis are unncessary in this case, as it is an argument to the `setTimeout` function call and therefore an expression anyway.

The term IIFE does not only refer to the statement form of this pattern, where the [parenthesis would be necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1634268/1048572).

Answer (score 0):

The parantheses are optional in your example of an immediately invoked function.

```
(function() {
  // some code
})();
```

Can be re-written as

```
function() {
  // some code
}();
```

So the `i` in the example function's call becomes the `x` in the function definition.

```
function(x) { // x = 1
    return function() { 
        console.log(x); // x = 1
    }; 
}(1)
```