# How javascript implements callback?

Tags: javascript, callback

I've used some callbacks in JS, I want to know `how JS implements the callback mechanism`. What is the `principle` of callback in JavaScript?

Thx.

Comment: Right now, there must be like a dozen major JavaScript engines. You'll have to be more specific.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario thx a lot, next time my question will be more specific. As beginner in JS, I am just curious about how callback work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930272/javascript-closures-vs-anonymous-functions - the answer sought will most likely be found in these questions. If not, please make sure a more speific question is asked.

Comment: @user2864740 thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Functions are first class objects, thus they can be passed around like any other kind of object.

You pass a function as an argument to another function call, then you call it later.

Comment: Thx a lot. I can understand it now but my question should be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Just because functions are first-class objects, we can pass a function as an argument in another function and later execute that passed-in function or even return it to be executed later. This is the essence of using callback functions in JavaScript

Comment: Thx a lot. I can understand it now but my question should be more specific.