# Javascript - how event listeners work under the hood

Tags: javascript, function, events, listener

I have the following code:

```
function sayHiLater(){
    var greeting = "Hi!";
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(greeting);

    }, 3000); 
    console.log("Hello before hi");
}

sayHiLater();
```

I would like to better understand how event listeners work under the hood,
so in my example above, as setTimeOut is being executed, what really happens?
I know it creates a new execution context, but my question is; does that execution context is simply being delayed for 3 seconds, meaning the execution stack is moving on to other things in the meanwhile, and as the 3 seconds are over it comes back to that execution context, or is it simply passing to the browser engine some sort of a reference of the anonymous function argument, telling it when to fire, and then right away the setTimeOut execution context is being popped off the execution stack. Or am I  just completely far off from what's really happening. Thank you for your time.

Comment: simple implementation may be: post event into the event queue -> make an executor pull the first event from the event queue-> make the executor look for the evnet callback (from let's say, a map) -> execute the event callback

Comment: I removed my answer because I saw this question a possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930272/javascript-closures-vs-anonymous-functions

Answer (score 0):

> Is it simply passing to the browser engine some sort of a reference of the anonymous function argument, telling it when to fire, and then right away the `setTimeOut` execution context is being popped off the execution stack.

Yes, that's exactly what is happening. The `setTimeout` execution context immediately returns (and jumps to the next statement, your `console.log`).

Then after your current turn completes and no more code is to execute, the engine goes back to the event loop and waits for something to happen. After 3 seconds, the time is ready to fire the callback, and when no other code is already executing the event loop starts the anonymous function.
So `setTimeout` does not really *call* its callback, it only *schedules* it for later. It will be called by the event loop itself when the timer has run out.

Notice that the anonymous function that is put on the timer is a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/1048572) (it closes over the `greeting` variable), so the variable environment ("scope") of `sayHiLater` will be retained (not garbage-collected) even after the `sayHiLater` execution context is popped off the stack, until the callback is going to be executed.

Comment: Hey, well the guy above you said that the execution context isn't over, but the execution stack simply moves on to the next thing until the 3 seconds passed, and then it comes back to it(if nothing else is on the stack) and executes that anon function

Comment: I was referring to @ambodi comment's.

Comment: @user2081462: He might not known what he's talking about :-) Which execution context do you mean, the global one, `sayHiLater()`s one, `setTimeout(…)`s one or the anon callback's one?

Comment: I was talking about setTimeout execution context - once you pass arguments to it and execute it, a new execution context happens. My question was - will javascript simply start the execution context, see that there's 3 seconds delay, move on to other things, and then return to the execution context of setTimeout once 3 seconds have passed? or is it the other thing. and btw I am curious to know if it's true to all event listeners.

Comment: An execution context is the "stack frame". It only exists during the call. Due to JS' single-threaded nature, and its synchronous run-to-completion (per eventloop turn) model, they typically don't exist very long. Not sure what "*isn't over*" is supposed to mean

Comment: I just wrote another comment to clarify, see above

Comment: You pass arguments to the call of  `setTimeout`, which creates an execution context for the `setTimeout` call (which is implementation-specific, as `setTimeout` is a native host function). It creates a timer and schedules the callback argument, and immediately returns, and with that return the execution context is destroyed. Then when 3 seconds have passed and the event loop picks up the timer, the event loop calls the anon callback. Only then the execution context for the callback will be created.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94357/discussion-between-user2081462-and-bergi).