# javascript using non-inline function

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

I'm using the 'binary-parser' NPM module in node.js and am trying to use my own 'assert' function instead of supplying it inline.  I don't know if the problem is that of 'binary-parser' or is that of my ignorance of calling functions and/or function references in javascript.

Here's the code that works but not what I want:

```
var Parser = require('binary-parser').Parser;

var data = new Buffer([0x23, 0x36, 0x74, 0x0e, 0x01, 0xff, 0xff]);

function range (min, val, max) {
    return (min <= val && val <= max);
}
var dataParser = new Parser()
.endianess('little')
.uint8('inside_humidity', {assert: function(x){return(x <= 100);}})
.uint16('barometer', {assert: function(x){return(20000 <= x && x <= 32500);},
     formatter: function(x) {return x/1000;}})
.uint16('wind_direction', {assert: function(x){return(x <= 360);}})
.uint16('crc');

console.log(dataParser.parse(data));
```

I'd like to call my own 'range' function like this:

```
    .uint16('barometer',
        {assert: range(20000, x, 32500),
     formatter: function(x) {return x/1000;}})
```

But I get:

```
ReferenceError: x is not defined
```

So I tried:

```
assert: function(x){range(20000, x, 325000)}
```

and

```
{assert: function(x){range.bind(this, 20000, x, 32500)},
```

and get:

```
ReferenceError: range is not defined
```

Is it possible to do what I want?

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930272/javascript-closures-vs-anonymous-functions is an interesting and helpful read?

Comment: Thank you and I found this to be even more helpful (at least to me): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use a closure:

```
function range(min, max) {
    return function(x) {
        return min <= val && val <= max;
    };
}
```

With that you can write

```
…
.uint8('inside_humidity', {assert: range(-Infinity, 100)})
.uint16('barometer', {assert: range(20000, 32500), formatter: function(x) {return x/1000;}})
.uint16('wind_direction', {assert: range(-Infinity, 360)})
…
```

Comment: That comes back 'min is not defined'.  It recognizes 'min' and 'max' outside of 'function(x)' but not inside of it.  I tried: `function range (someMin, someMax) {
    var min = someMin;
    var max = someMax;
    return function(x) {
 return min <= x && x <= max;
    };
}`
and it still did not recognize 'min' inside function(x).

Comment: Oh my, what a horrible library. It [stringifies the function](https://github.com/keichi/binary-parser/blob/master/lib/binary_parser.js#L316) which makes closures impossible. You should file a bug.

Comment: @kevdev: As a workaround, `function range(min, max) { return new Function("x", "return "+JSON.stringify(min)+" <= x && x <= "+JSON.stringify(max)+";"); }` should do it.

Comment: Wow, I never would've come up with that but it works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
.uint16('barometer', {assert: function(x){return range(20000, x, 32500);},
```

HTH

Comment: It still comes back 'range is not defined'.