# Arrow function is not working inside AJAX onload. But if i write it as a normal function then it works

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

When I am using an arrow function in `xhr.onload`, I don't get a response. However, if I use a normal function like `xhr.onload = function(){}` then I get the response. Why does the code before not work like it does when using `xhr.onload = function(){}`?

```
let btn = document.getElementById("button");

btn.addEventListener("click" , function(){
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET" , "sample.txt" , true);
xhr.onload = () => {
    if(this.status === 200){
         console.log(this.responseText);
    }
}
xhr.send();
})
```

Comment: Don't use `this` inside `onload` callback. It doesn't refer to `xhr` as you think. So use `xhr` instead `this`.

Comment: @hindmost you beat me to it, +1

Comment: @hindmost You shouldnt post what is essentially a complete answer as a comment. That is an abuse of the comment system. If somebody posts an incorrect answer as a comment there is no way to vote the answer down and  the OP may think it is  true.

Comment: It's not an incorrect answer if its posted as a comment.

Comment: @RakibUddin you should read on on [fat arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28372106/2647442) and [javascript closures](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12931785/2647442). If you plan on sticking with javscript you will NEED to know about these

Comment: @Andy Comments are for asking for clarification and providing advice. not answering questions. What you posted is an answer to the question the OP was asking. That is an abuse of the comment system because users cant vote on the answer you supplied. "Answer" being "a thing said, written, or done to deal with or as a reaction to a question,", not the thing created when you click the answer button.

Comment: If comments are for "asking for clarification and providing advice" isn't what you're doing an abuse of the comment system? Perhaps this should be taken to meta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The context of this of the onload function should be the original XMLHttpRequest, but using the arrow function you don't have a context assigned so the this will more than likely be parent scope or window.  That's going to be the issue.