# Why doesn't this cycling function in javaScript return 0 every time? How would I do something similar in python?

Tags: javascript, python, function, counter, cycle

I'm new to programming and am learning a bit of javaScript after knowing a bit of Python. I'm using javaScript to control elements inside a mobile AR app and I created a very simple cycler function that works exactly as I want it to but honestly I'm trying to understand WHY it works! I wanted a function that would cycle 1,2,3 on each tap. First tap would return '1', second tap '2', third tap '3', then repeat this sequence on additional taps. Here is what I came up with after lots of trial, error and googling:

```js
const cycler = {
     current: -1,
     cycle: function() {
      if (cycler.current == 3) {
       cycler.current = 0;
      } else {
       cycler.current++;
      }
      console.log(cycler.current);
     }
}

cycler.cycle()
cycler.cycle()
cycler.cycle()
cycler.cycle()
cycler.cycle()
```

On the tap event, I call cycler.cycle(); and it works...returning 1,2,3,1,2,3,etc. corresponding to my taps...but I don't understand why it doesn't just return 0 every time I tap. Why isn't 'current' being reset to '-1' every time I call this? How would I do something similar in python? How do I think about this? Thanks for any insight!

Comment: It is printing `0,1,2,3`. can't reproduce problem

Comment: OP indicated "I created a very simple cycler function that works exactly as I want it to but honestly I'm trying to understand WHY it works!", so printing the desired output is, in fact, "reproducing the problem", so to speak.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closures vs. anonymous functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930272/javascript-closures-vs-anonymous-functions)

Comment: @SherylHohman.... Care to elaborate or help me understand what makes you suspect that this is a duplicate? Elaborating could help me understand new concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `cycler` is an object literal in javascript.
It has a property, `current`, and a method, `cycle`.
Calling the method does not re-create the object, it just runs the function.
As you know, the function simply increments the value of the `current` property (unless the current value is `3`, of course, in which case it resets the value to `0`.)

In python you might make a class that creates a counter object. Its constructor would contain code very similar to the object you created here.
If you keep making new instances from that class and call `.cycle` once on each instance, your log will contain a bunch of `0`s as you were expecting.
However, if you call `.cycle` on the same instance repeatedly, you'll get the behavior you found here.

Answer (score 1):

When the object gets created in memory it sets the initial current value to -1, and unless the object gets removed, and recreated in memory, the value will be whatever you last set it to.