# function inside of function runs with body

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Below is an example from the book "Async & performance" form Kyle simpson.

Trying to understand below code and I have questions
1)what is the point of passing in fetchX and fetchY?
2)how does getX and getY run?
I can imagine running w/ getX() and getY() but code has getX(){} and getY(){} and that looks more like function declaration? Am i wrong here?

```
function add(getX,getY,cb) {
  var x, y;
  getX( function(xVal){
    x = xVal;
    if (y != undefined) {
       cb(x + y );
    }
  });
  getY( function(yVal){
    y = yVal;
    if (x != undefined) {
         cb(x + y);
    }
  })
}

// fetchX() and fetch() are sync or async functions
add(fetchX, fetchY, function(sum) {
   console.log(sum);
});
```

Comment: "*code has getX(){} and getY(){}*" - no it doesn't. It has `getX(…);` and `getY(…);`, passing a **function expression** `function(…) { … }` as an argument

Comment: ok, so function expression runs like below
const getRectArea = function(width, height) {
  return width * height;
};

console.log(getRectArea(3, 4));

How does this ever run?

Comment: It doesn't run. It's passed to `getX`/`getY`, which will run it later.

Comment: so perhaps this code is impartial.. as from this little snippets.. those will never run.. but also, function expression.. without assigning to something, how will it ever run?

Comment: @javascript It would help if you could link the full example from the book. Surely there's a definition of `fetchX` and `fetchY` somewhere

Comment: made edit and insert of definition of the fetchX and Y... as it just comes in comment..  as this is just abstraction to prove the concept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question we can analyze the code example. If we read the code from top to bottom and from left to right (note that even though that is how code is parsed, that is **NOT** how code is executed, but we will come back to that), we first see

```
function add(getX,getY,cb) {
  var x, y;
  // ...
}
```

This is a declaration for a function named `add`, with 3 parameters named `getX`, `getY` and `cb`.

The first line inside the function body is

```
  var x, y;
```

A `var` keyword inside a function body means this is a [function-scoped variable declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var). This just means that `x` and `y` are declared from the start to the end of the `add` function body (the `var` keyword can also be used for globally-scoped variable declarations, there is also the `let` keyword for block-scoped variable declaration).

The next code part is

```
  getX( function(xVal){
    x = xVal;
    if (y != undefined) {
       cb(x + y );
    }
  });
```

This starts with a call to `getX(...);` (remember `getX` is the first parameter of the `add` function that we are in). So `getX` has to be something that we can call, i.e. a function, otherwise we will get a runtime error.

The first (and only) input parameter that is passed to the `getX` call is

```
  function(xVal){
    x = xVal;
    if (y != undefined) {
       cb(x + y );
    }
  }
```

which is a [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#the_function_expression_function_expression).

> The function keyword can be used to define a function inside an expression.

Using a `function` keyword in this way (or using [an arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)) without specifying a name, defines an anonymous function. You might hear others refer to them (depending on context) as [callbacks/lambdas/closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930272/javascript-closures-vs-anonymous-functions).

So this tells us that the `getX` function should accept a function as the first parameter and potentially call it as part of its internal logic.

We also notice that this anonymous function `function(xVal){ ... }` accepts a single parameter `xVal`. This tells us that the `getX` function should pass some value as the first parameter when (if) it calls this function.

So if the `getX` function ever calls back this anonymous function that we are passing as its first parameter, then the body of this anonymous function will be executed. If the `getX` function never calls it, then the body of this anonymous function will never be executed.

The body of the anonymous function is

```
    x = xVal;
    if (y != undefined) {
       cb(x + y );
    }
```

which just assigns `xVal` to `x` and conditionally calls `cb(x + y)`, i.e. the third parameter of the `add` function, which is still the outer function scope here.

We could do a similar breakdown for the `getY` call. The only difference would be that it calls the `getY` function parameter and the body of the anonymous function assigns `yVal` to y (but it still conditionally calls `cb(x + y)`).

The last few lines of the code example are

```
// fetchX() and fetch() are sync or async functions
add(fetchX, fetchY, function(sum) {
  console.log(sum);
});
```

So this is a call of the previously declared named function `function add(getX, getY, cb) { ... }`.

When this code line is executed it will call `add` with

- 1st parameter: `fetchX`
- 2nd parameter: `fetchY`
- 3rd parameter: an anonymous function `function(sum) { console.log(sum); }`. This anonymous function accepts a single parameter `sum` and only when (if) called it logs it to the console.

---

> 1. what is the point of passing in fetchX and fetchY?

As we see from the breakdown above, `fetchX` and `fetchY` are passed into the `add` function call in order for them to serve as "replacements" for calls to `getX` and `getY` inside the function body. You can think of it that the call to `getX(...)` calls `fetchX(...)` and the call to `getY(...)` calls `fetchY(...)`.

They will be "called back" from inside the function, that's why in such cases we call them **callbacks**, they are functions passed as parameters into another function, and said other function *might* call them based on its internal logic. In your example they are called once each (assuming no errors happen during runtime).

---

> 2. How does getX and getY run? I can imagine running w/ getX() and getY() but code has getX(){} and getY(){} and that looks more like function declaration?

As mentioned earlier the code is not always executed from top to bottom and from left to right. So after parsing the code from the example, the code interpreter will execute the `add` call first (because the rest is just a declaration for the `add` function) and it will pass `fetchX`, `fetchY` and `function(sum){ console.log(sum); }` as the parameters. Right after the call happens the execution continues with the `add` function body.

Right from the `getX` call inside the `add` function body there are different possible flows, depending on what the logic inside the `getX` and `getY` is (specifically `fetchX` and `fetchY` in your case). Since we don't have a documentation for `fetchX` and `fetchY` nor their source code, **we cannot know how the code will execute** from here on. **But we can explore some of the possible flows.**

*I added a few `console.log` statements to your original code example. In that way we can see the order of the execution. Another way to do this, without the need to add extra log statements, is to use the debugger, place a breakpoint somewhere inside the function and then use the step commands to step through the code as it executes.*

**Option 1:** If both `fetchX` and `fetchY` call their first parameter (the callback they receive) always exactly once synchronously then the flow is (run the code snippet)

```js
// These two callbacks could be defined elsewhere, maybe even in code not under our control, such as in a library...
fetchX = function(callback) {
  callback(2); // unconditional single synchronous call
};
fetchY = function(callback) {
  callback(3); // unconditional single synchronous call
};

console.log("Entering the code example scope");

function add(getX,getY,cb) {
  console.log("Called: function add(getX,getY,cb)");
  var x, y;
  getX( function(xVal){
console.log("Called: function(xVal) xVal =", xVal);
x = xVal;
if (y != undefined) {
   cb(x + y);
}
  });
  getY( function(yVal){
console.log("Called: function(yVal) yVal =", yVal);
y = yVal;
if (x != undefined) {
   cb(x + y);
}
  });
  console.log("Returning from: function add(getX,getY,cb)");
}

add(fetchX, fetchY, function(sum) {
  console.log("Called: function(sum)");
  console.log(sum);
  console.log("Returning from: function(sum)");
});
console.log("Leaving the code example scope");
```

**Option 2:** If `fetchX` calls its callback always exactly once synchronously and `fetchY` calls its callback parameter always exactly once asynchronously, then the flow is (run the code snippet)

```js
fetchX = function(callback) {
  callback(2); // unconditional single synchronous call
};
fetchY = function(callback) {
  setTimeout(function() { callback(3); }, 0); // unconditional single asynchronous call
};

console.log("Entering the code example scope");

// add function is same as before, just in one line for space purposes
function add(getX,getY,cb) {
  console.log("Called: function add(getX,getY,cb)");
  var x, y; getX( function(xVal){ console.log("Called: function(xVal) xVal =", xVal); x = xVal; if (y != undefined) { cb(x + y); } }); getY( function(yVal){  console.log("Called: function(yVal) yVal =", yVal); y = yVal; if (x != undefined) { cb(x + y); } });
  console.log("Returning from: function add(getX,getY,cb)");
}

add(fetchX, fetchY, function(sum) {
  console.log("Called: function(sum)");
  console.log(sum);
  console.log("Returning from: function(sum)");
});
console.log("Leaving the code example scope");
```

**Option 3:** If `fetchX` calls its callback always exactly once asynchronously and `fetchY` calls its callback parameter always exactly once synchronously, then the flow is (run the code snippet)

```js
fetchX = function(callback) {
  setTimeout(function() { callback(2); }, 0); // unconditional single asynchronous call
};
fetchY = function(callback) {
  callback(3); // unconditional single synchronous call
};

console.log("Entering the code example scope");

// add function is same as before, just in one line for space purposes
function add(getX,getY,cb) {
  console.log("Called: function add(getX,getY,cb)");
  var x, y; getX( function(xVal){ console.log("Called: function(xVal) xVal =", xVal); x = xVal; if (y != undefined) { cb(x + y); } }); getY( function(yVal){  console.log("Called: function(yVal) yVal =", yVal); y = yVal; if (x != undefined) { cb(x + y); } });
  console.log("Returning from: function add(getX,getY,cb)");
}

add(fetchX, fetchY, function(sum) {
  console.log("Called: function(sum)");
  console.log(sum);
  console.log("Returning from: function(sum)");
});
console.log("Leaving the code example scope");
```

**Option 4:** If both `fetchX` and `fetchY` call their callback always exactly once asynchronously and `fetchX` calls it sooner, then the flow is (run the code snippet)

```js
fetchX = function(callback) {
  setTimeout(function() { callback(2); }, 0); // unconditional single asynchronous call
};
fetchY = function(callback) {
  setTimeout(function() { callback(3); }, 50); // unconditional single asynchronous call (further delayed)
};

console.log("Entering the code example scope");

// add function is same as before, just in one line for space purposes
function add(getX,getY,cb) {
  console.log("Called: function add(getX,getY,cb)");
  var x, y; getX( function(xVal){ console.log("Called: function(xVal) xVal =", xVal); x = xVal; if (y != undefined) { cb(x + y); } }); getY( function(yVal){  console.log("Called: function(yVal) yVal =", yVal); y = yVal; if (x != undefined) { cb(x + y); } });
  console.log("Returning from: function add(getX,getY,cb)");
}

add(fetchX, fetchY, function(sum) {
  console.log("Called: function(sum)");
  console.log(sum);
  console.log("Returning from: function(sum)");
});
console.log("Leaving the code example scope");
```

**Option 5:** If both `fetchX` and `fetchY` call their callback always exactly once asynchronously and `fetchY` calls it sooner, then the flow is (run the code snippet)

```js
fetchX = function(callback) {
  setTimeout(function() { callback(2); }, 50); // unconditional single asynchronous call (further delayed)
};
fetchY = function(callback) {
  setTimeout(function() { callback(3); }, 0); // unconditional single asynchronous call
};

console.log("Entering the code example scope");

// add function is same as before, just in one line for space purposes
function add(getX,getY,cb) {
  console.log("Called: function add(getX,getY,cb)");
  var x, y; getX( function(xVal){ console.log("Called: function(xVal) xVal =", xVal); x = xVal; if (y != undefined) { cb(x + y); } }); getY( function(yVal){  console.log("Called: function(yVal) yVal =", yVal); y = yVal; if (x != undefined) { cb(x + y); } });
  console.log("Returning from: function add(getX,getY,cb)");
}

add(fetchX, fetchY, function(sum) {
  console.log("Called: function(sum)");
  console.log(sum);
  console.log("Returning from: function(sum)");
});
console.log("Leaving the code example scope");
```

**Option 6:** If `fetchX` calls its callback exactly three times asynchronously on an interval of 30ms with values 10, 20, 30 and `fetchY` calls its callback exactly three times asynchronously on an interval of 50ms with values 1, 2, 3, then the flow is (run the code snippet)

```js
fetchX = function(callback) {
  setTimeout(function() { callback(10); }, 30);
  setTimeout(function() { callback(20); }, 60);
  setTimeout(function() { callback(30); }, 90);
};
fetchY = function(callback) {
  setTimeout(function() { callback(1); },  50);
  setTimeout(function() { callback(2); }, 100);
  setTimeout(function() { callback(3); }, 150);
};

console.log("Entering the code example scope");

// add function is same as before, just in one line for space purposes
function add(getX,getY,cb) {
  console.log("Called: function add(getX,getY,cb)");
  var x, y; getX( function(xVal){ console.log("Called: function(xVal) xVal =", xVal); x = xVal; if (y != undefined) { cb(x + y); } }); getY( function(yVal){  console.log("Called: function(yVal) yVal =", yVal); y = yVal; if (x != undefined) { cb(x + y); } });
  console.log("Returning from: function add(getX,getY,cb)");
}

add(fetchX, fetchY, function(sum) {
  console.log("Called: function(sum)");
  console.log(sum);
  console.log("Returning from: function(sum)");
});
console.log("Leaving the code example scope");
```

Here are the outputs of the above options

**Option 1:**

```
Entering the code example scope
Called: function add(getX,getY,cb)
Called: function(xVal) xVal = 2
Called: function(yVal) yVal = 3
Called: function(sum)
5
Returning from: function(sum)
Returning from: function add(getX,getY,cb)
Leaving the code example scope
```

**Option 2:**

```
Entering the code example scope
Called: function add(getX,getY,cb)
Called: function(xVal) xVal = 2
Returning from: function add(getX,getY,cb)
Leaving the code example scope
Called: function(yVal) yVal = 3
Called: function(sum)
5
Returning from: function(sum)
```

**Option 3:**

```
Entering the code example scope
Called: function add(getX,getY,cb)
Called: function(yVal) yVal = 3
Returning from: function add(getX,getY,cb)
Leaving the code example scope
Called: function(xVal) xVal = 2
Called: function(sum)
5
Returning from: function(sum)
```

**Option 4:**

```
Entering the code example scope
Called: function add(getX,getY,cb)
Returning from: function add(getX,getY,cb)
Leaving the code example scope
Called: function(xVal) xVal = 2
Called: function(yVal) yVal = 3
Called: function(sum)
5
Returning from: function(sum)
```

**Option 5:**

```
Entering the code example scope
Called: function add(getX,getY,cb)
Returning from: function add(getX,getY,cb)
Leaving the code example scope
Called: function(yVal) yVal = 3
Called: function(xVal) xVal = 2
Called: function(sum)
5
Returning from: function(sum)
```

**Option 6:**

```
Entering the code example scope
Called: function add(getX,getY,cb)
Returning from: function add(getX,getY,cb)
Leaving the code example scope
Called: function(xVal) xVal = 10
Called: function(yVal) yVal = 1
Called: function(sum)
11
Returning from: function(sum)
Called: function(xVal) xVal = 20
Called: function(sum)
21
Returning from: function(sum)
Called: function(xVal) xVal = 30
Called: function(sum)
31
Returning from: function(sum)
Called: function(yVal) yVal = 2
Called: function(sum)
32
Returning from: function(sum)
Called: function(yVal) yVal = 3
Called: function(sum)
33
Returning from: function(sum)
```

There are of course more possible flows. Either of the functions could synchronously or asynchronously call its callback multiple times (not just a single time), or it could call it on an interval forever or it could call it conditionally - so sometimes not even once.

As you can see from all the possibilities above, without the documentation or source code for functions `fetchX` and `fetchY`, it is impossible to determine what the flow is. Also the flow will dynamically change based on what functions are passed in.

You can just copy any of the code snippets above and change the logic inside `fetchX` and `fetchY` and explore yourself other flows that you are interested in.